# Java : Unable to get the List size during Thread Processing

Tags: java, multithreading

I am processing a File in java  where  i am counting the number of occurrences of a particular Filed in every line of that file Where i am starting a Thread for every Line 
as shown below

```
input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(finaName)));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
FileThread t = new FileThread(line);
t.start();
    }

FileThread st = new FileThread();
System.out.println("Size"+st.list.size());
```

**FileThread.java**

```
public class FileThread extends Thread
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public FileThread(){}
public FileThread(String line){}
private String line = null;
    public void run() {
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\|", LIST.length);
            String Symbol = null;
            try {
            Symbol = tokens[4];
                    list.add(symbol);

            } catch (Throwable t1) {
                t1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

The problem is that i am always getting the Size as 0 .
please see the sample output

**BIM!A
BIM!B
BIM!C
BIM!D
Size0**

Comment: Java threads aren't lightweight.. Be careful about just how many you make

Comment: The character i split is  |

Comment: Please give your exact code. What you have written in your question won't even compile (`line` is not remembered in `FileThread` ctor but is used in `run()`. Also, `LIST` is not declared).

Comment: FileThread st = new FileThread();
System.out.println("Size"+st.list.size());

how did it compile first of all ? You don't have your zero argument constructor defined in your FileThread class!! ??

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code, that may help you

```
public class FileThread extends Thread {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private boolean inThread = false;
    .......
    public int getListSize() {
        if(!inThread)
            return list != null ? list.size() : 0 ;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public FileThread(String line) {
    }

    public void run() {
        inThread = true;
             // You logic of the thread
        inThread = false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
     ..............

     ..............

     ..............
        System.out.println("Size" + st.getListSize());
    }

}
```

Comment: doesn't compile  at  return list != null ? list.size() ? 0 ;

Comment: Thanks but still it is size is 0

Comment: Please see my updated answer, that you have to change in your code, other remains same in your code

Comment: Thanks a lot Bhavik , for your helping nature , anyway i solved that by using static in front of the list .